# Parse date in MomentJs ignoring some numbers

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What parse format string is needed to make an input string like this work in strict parsing mode?

```
moment('Feb 27 – Mar 12, 2017', 'MMM D - - - YYYY', true);
```

I need Moment.js to ignore some of the numbers in the input string, but can't find anything in [moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/) to let me specify what to ignore.  If I use non-strict mode, it sometimes works, but sometimes parses the wrong year.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj8fkvxv/) to illustrate.

Comment: Why do not you change the string before transmitting it at momentjs ?

Comment: @R3tep, I thought that since I'm specifying the format, I should not have to alter the input string and let the parser take care of it.

Comment: Answer from moment.js: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3831.